# Как в sql сначала вывести записи с указанным значением поля, а потом все остальные?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Есто поле в базе данных, принимающее некоторые значения, например - `character`, `environment`, `vehicle`. Надо сначала вывести записи где это поле принимает значение, заданное пользователем, например `character`, а потом - все остальное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

отвечаю на свой вопрос

```
SELECT *
FROM content
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN type LIKE 'character' THEN 1
END DESC
```